Is There a Dynamic Sandbox Environment Available for Testing with Amazon Selling Partner API?
I'm currently working on integrating the Amazon Selling Partner API into my application. I've successfully called the static sandbox provided by Amazon, but I'm looking for a way to test various API functionalities without affecting live data. Specifically, I'm interested in finding out if there's a dynamic sandbox environment available that allows for more realistic testing scenarios.
postman call for Static sandbox
Does Amazon provide such a dynamic sandbox for the Selling Partner API, or are there any third-party services that offer this capability for free?
Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
I have successfully called the static sandbox environment provided by Amazon for the Selling Partner API. In the static sandbox, I can perform some basic API operations and get predefined responses. However, I was hoping to find a dynamic sandbox environment that allows for more comprehensive testing scenarios. Specifically, I want to be able to retrieve various entities dynamically, simulating real-world conditions without impacting live data.
I expected to find either an official dynamic sandbox from Amazon or a third-party service that provides this kind of testing environment for free. Unfortunately, my research so far has not led to any viable solutions.

Yes, a dynamic sandbox is available as you can check here.
The only problem is that it is supported only for a small subset of SP-API calls.
Check here to understand how to perform a call to the dynamic sandbox.

I have already reviewed the documentation, which mentions, "If the operation contains the object at the path or operation level, the dynamic sandbox is supported."
I searched for the "x-amzn-api-sandbox": { "dynamic": {} } key in the Order Swagger model JSON but did not find it. You can refer to the Order Swagger model JSON here.
Does this imply that the dynamic sandbox is not supported for the Order API?

Exactly. If no "dynamic" key is in the model, then the Dynamic Sandbox is not supported for that API.
